# How to convert Fortran subarray syntax like X(:,J) to VB.NET and C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, fortran

I have come across some Fortran I am converting, like the following

```
DO J = 1 , N
   C(:,J) = C(:,J) * X(J)
ENDDO
```

and believe I need to explicitly write code to loop through the first dimension as well.  In VB.Net
this would be:

```vb
For j = 1 to N
   For i = 1 to C.GetLength(0)-1
      C(i,j) = C(i,j) * X(j)
   Next k
Next j
```

and in C#, this would be

```cs
for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
{
   for (int i = 1; i < C.GetLength(0); i++)
   {
      C(i,j) = C(i,j) * X(j);
   }
}
```

Is this correct?  I do need only to pull the first dimension off of the C matrix.

Comment: Note that Fortran is column major regarding the data ordering and C# (and probably also VB.Net) is row major. Also the indices of an array for Fortran start with 1 and run to N whilst for C# they will start at 0 and end at N-1.

Comment: So then do not subtract 1 when X.GetLength(0) or  X.GetLength(0) are used, since FORTRAN arrays are not zero-bound?  What is column major vs. row major?  Isn't the element in the ith row and jth column in X(i,j) in VB.NET the same as the element in the ith row and jth column of X(i,j) in FORTRAN?

Comment: You should probably start your C# arrays with index 0 (actually it all depends how arrays are declared in Fortran and C#, Fortran arrays can start at 0 but by default they start at 1. Yes the ith column and jth colum could nmatch, but it all depends how everything is defined, logical rows and columns might for performance reasons not always match implementation rows and columns. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order

Comment: That looks ok Do note in vb you can declare your arrays to start at one like Dim MyBuf(1 to 5, 1 to 5) as integer. I think this would thus give you compatible code and array sizes, and also in general not have to start a 0, and also eliminate the need for a "-1" in most loops. As a result, you can concentrate more on syntax as opposed to code logic.

Comment: @albert It's probably more accurate to say that .NET is row-major.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Unfortunately, you can't do that in VB.NET.  For reasons unknown, they eliminated that syntax (or rather, they forced to to always be `0 To {n}`).  (Insert rant about arrays in .NET VB here.)  With a multi-dimensional array, you can still bodge together something with a non-zero lower bound using the right `Array` constructor.

Comment: Wow, you are correct. The VBA/VB6 syntax of dim mybuf(1 to 5, 1 to 5) as integer is not supported. I did not realize that. I would actually still suggest skipping and ignoring the 0 bounds when converting that Fortran code, as one then can use same logic in code, and just ignore the zero guy. But I stand 100% corrected here.